# 0% Coverage Junit 4

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

I'm working on the JUnit tests for these methods, I've spend a couple of hours trying to improve it with no success, the test is passing but I'm getting 0% coverage, any idea why am I getting that?

```
AuthService.java

    public String getUsers() {
        if (studentBean.getUsers() == null || checkIfTokenExpired()) {
            this.fetchStudents();
        }
        return studentBean.getUsers();
    }

    public boolean checkIfTokenExpired() {
        LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime expiryTime = setExpiryTime();
        boolean isTokenExpired = currentDateTime.isAfter(expiryTime);
        return isTokenExpired;
    }


JUnit test:


    @Mock
    StudentBean studentBean;

    @Mock
    AuthService authService;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testGetUsers(){
        Mockito.when(studentBean.getUsers()).thenReturn(null);
        Mockito.when(authService.checkIfTokenExpired()).thenReturn(false);
        Mockito.when(authService.getUsers()).thenReturn("APSAPS");
        assertEquals("APSAPS", authService.getUsers());
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: It’s because `authService` is mocked in the test, so none of the actual implementation is executed. You should only mock classses _other than_ the one being tested.

Comment: So should I use @Autowired on AuthService authService?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should inject the mocks in your AuthService.

You can do that using **@InjectMocks**

Also, since you want to test "getUsers" method you should not mock the method for it.

We only mock the methods of the mocked attributes not the service under test.

```java
    @Mock
    StudentBean studentBean;

    @InjectMocks
    AuthService authService;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testGetUsers(){
        Mockito.when(studentBean.getUsers()).thenReturn(null);
        //Mockito.when(authService.checkIfTokenExpired()).thenReturn(false);
        //Mockito.when(authService.getUsers()).thenReturn("APSAPS");
        // assertEquals("APSAPS", authService.getUsers());
        String result = authService.getUsers();
        //... perform assertions
    }
```

with this code your **fetchStudents** method will be triggered and you should Assert the same.